# Replicate RDS instance into a DEV instance

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, database-backups, database-restore

I have two RDS instances, one for PROD and other one for DEV. I want make daily backups of prod instance and replicate into a dev instance. The problem is that when I take a snapshot of prod instance, for restore that snapshot, AWS creates a new RDS instance.

What I want is bulk the new changes/data of the prod instance into a dev instance and daily have the same info in both instances.

Any ideas?

Comment: Database migration services can do what you describe. See this [aws blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/automating-database-migration-and-refreshing-activities-with-aws-dms/).